# How to Set my Mac's $PATH back the way it was before

Tags: terminal

I am just getting started with Terminal, the other day I might have messed something up with my `urs/local/bin`. When executing `echo $PATH` it returns me with `/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` the original path was `/usr/local/bin`.

How do I set it back to factory settings?

Comment: The $PATH you now have `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` is the default setting.

Answer (score 1):

By default the paths are saved in the file `/etc/paths`. You can edit it e.g. with `sudo vim /etc/paths`. Each line should contain one directory used for $PATH.

Then there is the directory `/etc/paths.d/` that can contain text files with paths in it.

Furthermore the path can be modified in the files `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile`.

---

However, the $PATH you are stating is the default one and usually desired. Restricting it to only `/usr/local/bin` would make a lot of default applications - like `vim`, `ls`, or even `sudo` that reside in `/usr/bin/` or `/bin/` - inaccessible without typing their whole paths every time.